# How can I promote a user to a network administrator?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I took over an existing multisite network and I don't have the privileges to promote anyone to network admin through the WP Admin UI directly. How can I promote my site administrator to network admin via MySQL and/or WP CLI?

Comment: you want to create a Network Admin (aka Super Admin) ?

Comment: no, I want to *promote* an existing admin to Super Admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Wordpress MU Network Admin via Database](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72871/add-wordpress-mu-network-admin-via-database)

Comment: then why did you asked? Use google first, that's what recommended here!

Comment: Understood, I got linked to the other question from WP IRC after posting this one

Comment: I've submitted an answer using wp-cli which is probably the preferred method over directly modifying the database (although, in all honesty, in a case like this, there is very little difference).

Answer (score 2):

You might use grant_super_admin()

To add an admin by user ID you can use grant_super_admin. Simple put grant_super_admin in your theme’s functions.php file (usually in /wp-content/themes/CURRENT THEME NAME/functions.php). You’ll need to put the ID of the user as a variable, the example below we’re using the user ID of 1.

```
grant_super_admin(1);
```

https://drawne.com/add-super-admin-wordpress-network/

Or Some variation of this should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Your Name', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.test.com/', '2011-06-07 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Name');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');



INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: I already have a user with those capabilities. What I need is to promote the user to MULTISITE admin.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the command line and can use [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/), then you need to run two commands (assuming your site ID is 1):

`wp network meta get 1 site_admins`

This will return an array of all the site admins. Here is a sample array:

```
array (
  0 => 'user',
  1 => 'tedmasterweb',
  2 => 'fredflintston',
  3 => 'jcollins',
)
```

You then need to execute the following command setting the key as **4** (one more than the highest number in the array above), e.g.:

`wp network meta patch insert 1 site_admins 4 myusername`

You might then need to log out and log back in to see the change.

**Related documentation**

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/network/meta/update/

Answer (score 1):

Can you see this in user edit?

[image]

Comment: no, as I said in the original question _I don't have the privileges to promote anyone to network admin through the WP Admin UI directly_.