# Change Administrator to Super Administrator (multi-site)

Tags: multisite

Could someone help me how to change Administrator to Super Administrator on a multi-site?

Comment: Run [`grant_super_admin( id )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/grant_super_admin/) once?

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user in wp and I got involved in this difficult situation. If you mean to run this command on editor, my answer is no because there is no editor. Can I run this command also to the file in server: wp-includes/capabilities.php?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. One would be to change the values in the database directly (explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72871/add-wordpress-mu-network-admin-via-database)). However, this easily introduces errors, so I don't prefer it.

---

The other method is to use [`grant_super_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/grant_super_admin/) with the user's ID. The default admin's ID is 1 and there are [various methods to find other users' ID's](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/get-user-id.html).

Say the ID of the user you want to make a super admin is `n`. This code now needs to be run (at least) once. One of the easiest ways to make sure it will be is to download the *functions.php* of the active theme.

You could just add it to the top of the file and it will probably work. But it is safer to run code inside hooks. In the TwentySeventeen theme this could be the `twentyseventeen_setup()` method. Just add this line

```
grant_super_admin( n );
```

Now visit the site, and make sure it worked. Then you can safely remove this code again.